# R Parallel Package: clusterExport to each individual core rather than one large object to all cores

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm using the Parallel Package to save me some time in R.  Usually I export whatever object I am trying to do calculations on with clusterExport and run the relevant function.  However, this time I'm working with a very large object (10+GB) and even creating a small cluster uses a ton of RAM.  The calculation I'm doing only requires a part of the 10 GB object for each copy of R.  I'm wondering if there is a way to use clusterExport to only export the relevant half gigabyte or so to each copy of R.  From what I can tell clusterExport always sends the entire object to each copy so if there is a work around to this please let me know.

You can see in this example below I store the data.frame x in each copy of R.  My goal would be in this case to have 10 different datasets x1-x10 and load x1 to the first copy, x2 to the second, and so on.  If there is another way to do this efficiently please let me know as well.

```
library('doParallel')
x <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=1:10)
test <- function(y) {
  return(x$a[y]+x$b[y])
}
cl <- makeCluster(10)
registerDoParallel(cl)
clusterExport(cl,list('test','x'))
test1 <- parLapply(cl,1:10,fun=test)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: In this circumstance, will makeCluster(10) use 10 * 10GB of memory? Or does it only use 10GB and share it across the clusters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution to this after a few days.  The solution I came up with was to save each portion of the data.frame in seperate csv files.  Then within each virtual R session I read in the relevant csv file so each R session only contained the necessary data for their computations.